# Matplotlib Hist can't load or is taking too long?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, montecarlo, graph-visualization

I'm trying to plot a histogram based on monte carlo simulation with 10k iterations. Plotting using `plt.plot(price_list)` is fine but, the histogram doesn't load or it's taking extremely long(I think).

I've been running the code for an hour and gave up after it still doesn't load. I've tried changing the backend to qt5agg and lowering the bins to no avail.

The code works if I significantly lower the iteration. I've tried using 100 and the graphs plots just fine.

I'm using jupyter notebook to run. Below is the codes I've written.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
%matplotlib inline

plt.rc("axes.spines", top=False, right=False)

ticker = 'PG'
data = pd.DataFrame()
data[ticker] = wb.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', '2007-1-1')['Adj Close']

log_returns = np.log(data / data.shift(1))
u = log_returns.mean()
var = log_returns.var()
stdev = log_returns.std()
drift = u - (0.5 * var)

t_intervals = 250
iterations = 10000

daily_returns = np.exp(drift.values + stdev.values * norm.ppf(np.random.rand(t_intervals, iterations)))

s0 = data.iloc[-1]

price_list = np.zeros_like(daily_returns)
price_list[0] = s0

for t in range(1, t_intervals):
    price_list[t] = price_list[t - 1] * daily_returns[t]

plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
plt.plot(price_list);
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
plt.hist(price_list, bins = 20);
```